# Sort a subset of columns of a pandas dataframe alphabetically by column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble finding the solution to a fairly simple problem.

I would like to alphabetically arrange certain columns of a pandas dataframe that has over 100 columns (i.e. so many that I don't want to list them manually).

Example df:

```
import pandas as pd

subject = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]
timepoint = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,1,2,3,4,5,6]
c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]
d = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]
b = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame({'subject':subject,
                   'timepoint':timepoint,
                   'c':c,
                   'd':d,
                   'a':a,
                   'b':b})

df.head()

   subject  timepoint  c  d  a  b
0        1          1  2  2  2  2
1        1          2  3  3  3  3
2        1          3  4  4  4  4
3        1          4  5  5  5  5
4        1          5  6  6  6  6
```

How could I rearrange the column names to generate a df.head() that looks like this:

```
   subject  timepoint  a  b  c  d
0        1          1  2  2  2  2
1        1          2  3  3  3  3
2        1          3  4  4  4  4
3        1          4  5  5  5  5
4        1          5  6  6  6  6
```

i.e. keep the first two columns where they are and then alphabetically arrange the remaining column names.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split your your dataframe based on column names, using normal indexing operator `[]`, sort alphabetically the other columns using `sort_index(axis=1)`, and `concat` back together:

```
>>> pd.concat([df[['subject','timepoint']],
           df[df.columns.difference(['subject', 'timepoint'])]\
               .sort_index(axis=1)],ignore_index=False,axis=1)

    subject  timepoint  a  b  c  d
0         1          1  2  2  2  2
1         1          2  3  3  3  3
2         1          3  4  4  4  4
3         1          4  5  5  5  5
4         1          5  6  6  6  6
5         1          6  7  7  7  7
6         2          1  3  3  3  3
7         2          2  4  4  4  4
8         2          3  1  1  1  1
9         2          4  2  2  2  2
10        2          5  3  3  3  3
11        2          6  4  4  4  4
12        3          1  5  5  5  5
13        3          2  4  4  4  4
14        3          4  5  5  5  5
15        4          1  8  8  8  8
16        4          2  4  4  4  4
17        4          3  5  5  5  5
18        4          4  6  6  6  6
19        4          5  2  2  2  2
20        4          6  3  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the first two columns you want to keep (or determine them from the data), then sort all of the other columns. Use `.loc` with the correct list to then "sort" the DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np

first_cols = ['subject', 'timepoint']
#first_cols = df.columns[0:2].tolist()  # OR determine first two

other_cols = np.sort(df.columns.difference(first_cols)).tolist()

df = df.loc[:, first_cols+other_cols]
```

---

```
print(df.head())
   subject  timepoint  a  b  c  d
0        1          1  2  2  2  2
1        1          2  3  3  3  3
2        1          3  4  4  4  4
3        1          4  5  5  5  5
4        1          5  6  6  6  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the dataframe columns as a list, rearrange them, and assign it back to the dataframe using `df = df[cols]`

```
import pandas as pd

subject = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]
timepoint = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,1,2,3,4,5,6]
c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]
d = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]
b = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame({'subject':subject,
                   'timepoint':timepoint,
                   'c':c,
                   'd':d,
                   'a':a,
                   'b':b})

cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[:2] + sorted(cols[2:])
df = df[cols]
```